# Data posted from controller to view are different

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this form with kendo file upload, when the user uploads a file the action in the controller generates a random value, saves the value as the random value and sends the random value back to the client.
But it appears the random value differs in controller and the clients.
Below is the jquery code in the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/newlyTrained/Save',
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = data;
                alert(res.snumber );
            }
        });
    }

    function onRemove(e) {}

    function getFileInfo(e) {
        return $.map(e.files, function (file) {
            var info = file.name;
            return info;
        }).join(", ");
    }
</script>
```

And this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    string random = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            var physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Passports/" + random + extension);

            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);      
         }
     }
     return Json(new { snumber = random }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is the code for the kendo file upload in the view

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                            .Name("files")
                            .Multiple(false)
                            .Async(a => a
                        .Save("Save", "newlyTrained")
        .Remove("Remove", "newlyTrained")
                .AutoUpload(true)
            )
.Events(events => events
    .Success("onSuccess")
            .Remove("onRemove"))
                            )
```

I may be wrong but I'm suspecting the Save action in the controller is hit twice by the upload button and the jquery post

Comment: Hi, there seems to be an issue with your code. Do you post a file or a collection of files. As it seems, you post a collection of files. In this case a guid will be returned, despite the facet that many files will be stored.

Comment: What so you mean by the random value is different on the controller and the client? How do the strings differ?

Comment: The random value saved as the filename is different from the random value posted to the view in the alert